# Converting multi-digit char number to int

Tags: c++

I'm trying to input a number from the user (like `12345`) and turn it into an int. The code I'm using is:

```
int convertToNumber(char a[10]) {
    int output = 0;
    int b;
    int intArray[10];
    //Finds length
    for (int i = 0; a[i]!=0; i++) {
        if (a[i]==0) {
            b=i-1;
        }
    }
    //Runs through every letter.
    for (int i = 0; a[i]!=0; i++) {
        //Checks if user inputted anything but letter
        intArray[i] = a[i] - '0';
        //Multiplying it by the distance from the end
        intArray[i]= intArray[i] * (10^(b-i));
        //Adds to output
        output=+intArray[i];

    }
    return output;
}
```

however, this doesn't end up being anything like I hoped it would. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: ^ is not power in C/C++, this is bitwise xor. Maybe this is the source of your error.

Comment: x**y was the x to the power of y?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik In Python, surely. Not in C++. There's no operator in C++ for power.

Comment: Fortran too! I memorized that. Maybe pow(x,y) is in a c++ library.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik `std::pow(double, double)` and various overloads are in the C++ standard library, indeed.

Comment: Maybe this is an exercise where you manually need to implement this conversion, but just to be sure do you know the atoi function?

Comment: Yeah, somewhere I saw that ^ was to the power of operator.

Comment: @newbie Maybe that was in BASIC.

Comment: And no, I don't know the atoi function, and the thing I saw said it was c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an introduction to operators in C++. `10^(b-i)` is not 10 to the `(b-i)`th power, it's 10 XOR `b-i`. Also, for finding the length, don't roll your own function, use `std::strlen()`.

But you don't need an explicit length anyways: accumulate the product as you go along the string.

```
int my_str2int(const char *s)
{
    int res = 0;
    while (*s) {
        res *= 10;
        res += *s++ - '0';
    }

    return res;
}
```

Also, I just noticed the headline:

> I'm trying to input a number from the user (like 12345) and turn it into an int

If that's all you want:

```
long l = std::strtol("12345", NULL, 0);
unsigned long ul = std::strtoul("12345", NULL, 0);
long long ll = std::strtoll("12345", NULL, 0);
unsigned long long ull = std::strtoull("12345", NULL, 0);
int i = std::atoi("12345");
```

As usually, [the docs ain't evil](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: No, 12345 was just an example, and the code you just used doesn't work.

Comment: @newbie Hm, I don't follow?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant "12345" was the only thing I wanted to use.

Comment: @newbie I don't understand. Use in what sense? Of course if you want to write a function to convert a string to an integer, you'll have to use some other language constructs too. Obviously, if I assumed that you wanted to turn a string **constant** into an integer, I would have suggested you just write `int i = 12345;` instead. I'm not an idiot...

Answer (score 0):

You might try avoiding reinventing the wheel here.  Look up `strtoul` and `strtoull` to see if they are available on your system.  These handle numbers in different bases, too, and will give you a pointer to the first non-digit if your string contained a mixture of digits and non-digits.

And, as others have pointed out, `^` performs bitwise XOR.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm OK with not answering further.  :-)  And, it appears H2CO3 gave a pretty reasonable `atoi` anyway.

Comment: No, it's not homework, I'd never heard of these, and they didn't show up when I searched online earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You want use the pow function in the math library. ^ does xor.

Comment: Yes, `pow` is how you do exponentiation. No, that's not what's needed here; repeated multiplication and addition fits the input data much more naturally, and is faster.